# How to share struct within functions in C? (I got warnings: expected 'struct <anonymous> **')

Tags: c, pointers

I don't understand why this happens. I can call the read_png_file() and *data is there (I can see values set if I set any). But when I call next function then there is no data in there but it is type
(PNGDataPtr *) 0x22ff24 refering to (PNGDataPtr) 0x77c02850  Can you explain what happens there and how correct it? I want to pass the struct and share it between functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <png.h>

typedef struct
{
    FILE *fp;
} PNGData, *PNGDataPtr;


void read_png_file(char* file_name, PNGData * data)
{
}

void write_png_file(char* file_name, PNGDataPtr * data)
{
}

void process_file(PNGDataPtr * data)
{
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    PNGData data;
    read_png_file(argv[1], &data);
    process_file(&data);
    write_png_file(argv[2], &data);
    return 0;
}
```

> function 'main':|
>   warning: passing argument 1 of 'process_file' from incompatible pointer type 
>   main.c|19|note: expected 'struct  **' but argument is of type 'struct PNGData *'|
>   warning: passing argument 2 of 'write_png_file' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
>   15|note: expected 'struct  **' but argument is of type 'struct PNGData *'|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
void read_png_file(char* file_name, PNGData * data);
```

takes a pointer to a `PNGData` struct, but this

```
void write_png_file(char* file_name, PNGDataPtr * data);
```

takes a pointer to a pointer to a `PNGData` struct.

Don't mix `PNGDataPtr` and `PNGData *` - they're the same thing, and you're confusing yourself.

Ideally, get rid of `PNGDataPtr` entirely. If you're wedded to that idea, *always* use `PNGDataPtr` and *never* use `PNGData *`. Just don't mix them.

Comment: OMG, I am so blind. I did not see the differences even I thought I checked it carefully. I didn't see that I copied wrong word PNGDataPtr  instead PNGData

Answer (score 5):

In the declaration for write_png_file and process_file remove the *.  You've already declared PNGDataPtr a pointer.  Retaining the current idioms you should change the declarations to the following:

```
void write_png_file(char* file_name, PNGDataPtr data)
void process_file(PNGDataPtr data)
```

I'm assuming this a code fragment of your actual system; but idiomatically in C we avoid `typedef`ing purely for labeling something as a pointer to it's non-Ptr counterpart.  There are exceptions, such as building API and libraries for others where you desire to hide the underlying details.  I would recommend the following changes to the structure declaration to be more idiomatic:

```
typedef struct png_data_t
{
    FILE *fp;
} PNGData;
```

Naming the structure will provide better diagnostic and error messages from your compiler.  And the following changes to your method declarations:

```
void write_png_file(char* file_name, PNGData * data) { }
void process_file(PNGData * data) { }
```

Your main method shouldn't need to be modified.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand why it was called "anonymous struct".